# Permission denied for specific user

Tags: bash, ubuntu, teamcity, protocol-buffers

I logged into the `buildagent` of `teamcity`, accessing the shell using `/bin/sh` and execute the command protoc and it returns the error:

```
protoc failed error: /bin/sh: 1: protoc: Permission denied
```

The protoc is in `/bin/protoc/` and the directory has 777 permissions.

Comment: It's a really bad idea to make everyone have write access to an executable. When that is said, consider `ls /proc/1/root`. The `ls` executable can be executed by everyone, but the directory can only be read by root.

Comment: Yeah I know that its a bad idea. But I was just checking if that works, but it didn't helped either.

Comment: And what's your point by the second statement? You mean to say that the /bin/protoc is not readable by that user?

Comment: It might be that `protoc` is trying to access a file that it's not allowed to.

Comment: Since I am new to it, can you please tell me how to allow that?

Comment: I can't relly do anything, but guessing, as I don't know what `protoc` is.

Comment: here is [protoc](https://developers.google.com/protocol-buffers/), but its not really important to go into details. I tried moving the lib to `/protoc` or `/home/buildagent/protoc` added it to path. still not worked.

Answer (score 0):

I had the same issue.

What I found was that the error message was misleading.

Here's what worked for me:

try this:

```
protoc ./proto/hello/hello.proto --go_out=plugins=grpc:./outputDirectory -I ./proto/hello/hello.proto
```

Parts of the command obviously look redundant, but this was what I had to do to get it working.  I recommend trying this, and see if it runs.  If it does then you can see if you're able to tweak it, but I don't think so.

if "." is your output, then do this:

```
protoc ./proto/hello/hello.proto --go_out=plugins=grpc:. -I ./proto/hello/hello.proto
```

Notice that you don't need space.